# LINQ (.Contains()) query against whole DbSet

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

```
public List<DbSet> Get(String q = null)
{
    List<DbSet> objs = new List<DbSet>();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(q) && q != "undefined")
    {
        objs = from dealer in db.Dealers
               where dealer.Contains
               ......(?????)
    }
}
```

I have some 4 DbSets in my dbcontext class. I am able to run a search like this

```
objs = from dealer in db.Dealers
       where dealer.Name.Contains(q)
```

However I want to be able to do something similar except do the search against all the fields in dealer, and not just name. All the fields are strings

#### EDIT

Okay so I am starting to think this is not the best way to do what I'm trying to achieve. I'm looking into something called *"Full Text Search"*. Can someone either explain to me how this works in entity or give me a link to a good resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a linq extension method:

Checkout my blog post.
http://jnye.co/Posts/7/generic-iqueryable-or-search-on-multiple-properties-using-expression-trees

(classes are also in github: https://github.com/ninjanye/SearchExtensions)

```
public static IQueryable<T> Search<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string searchTerm, params Expression<Func<T, string>>[] stringProperties)  
{  
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))  
    {  
        return source;  
    }  

    var searchTermExpression = Expression.Constant(searchTerm);  

    //Variable to hold merged 'OR' expression  
    Expression orExpression = null;  
    //Retrieve first parameter to use accross all expressions  
    var singleParameter = stringProperties[0].Parameters.Single();  

    //Build a contains expression for each property  
    foreach (var stringProperty in stringProperties)  
    {  
        //Syncronise single parameter accross each property  
        var swappedParamExpression = SwapExpressionVisitor.Swap(stringProperty, stringProperty.Parameters.Single(), singleParameter);  

        //Build expression to represent x.[propertyX].Contains(searchTerm)  
        var containsExpression = BuildContainsExpression(swappedParamExpression, searchTermExpression);  

        orExpression = BuildOrExpression(orExpression, containsExpression);  
    }  

    var completeExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(orExpression, singleParameter);  
    return source.Where(completeExpression);  
}  

private static Expression BuildOrExpression(Expression existingExpression, Expression expressionToAdd)  
{  
    if (existingExpression == null)  
    {  
        return expressionToAdd;  
    }  

    //Build 'OR' expression for each property  
    return Expression.OrElse(existingExpression, expressionToAdd);  
}  

private static MethodCallExpression BuildContainsExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> stringProperty, ConstantExpression searchTermExpression)  
{  
    return Expression.Call(stringProperty.Body, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), searchTermExpression);  
}
```

You will also need this class:

```
//Create SwapVisitor to merge the parameters from each property expression into one  
public class SwapVisitor : ExpressionVisitor  
{  
    private readonly Expression from, to;  
    public SwapVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)  
    {  
        this.from = from;  
        this.to = to;  
    }  
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)  
    {  
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);  
    }  
    public static Expression Swap(Expression body, Expression from, Expression to)  
    {  
        return new SwapVisitor(from, to).Visit(body);  
    }  
}
```

You can then write something like:

```
db.Dealers.Search(q, x => x.Field1,    
                     x => x.Field2, 
                     ...  
                     x => x.Field20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no short cuts here:

```
objs = from dealer in db.Dealers
       where dealer.Name.Contains(q) || 
             dealer.Field2.Contains(q) ||
             ...
             dealer.Field20.Contains(q)
       select dealer;
```

You have to specify which fields you are going to search the value in.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually write conditions for all fields:

```
objs = from dealer in db.Dealers
       where dealer.Name.Contains(q) ||
             dealer.Foo.Contains(q) ||  
             // etc
             dealer.Bar.Contains(q)
       select dealer;
```

There is no simple way to tell Entity Framework to check all properties of entity for some condition.